# how to copy a 1d qvector into special column of 2d qvector?

Tags: memcpy, qvector

I'm gathering some 1D data (in qvector format). 
In my previous strategy, i use push-back method to add new 1d qvector to my 2D qvector.finally, i had a 2D qvector of my input 1D qvectors.
as this code:

```
Buf2D.push_back(Buf1D);
```

but now, i need to insert 1D qvector in a special column of 2D qvector. 
How i can do this?
I tried this :

```
Len = Buf1D.length()*sizeof(int);
    ptr = Len *index;
    memcpy(Buf2D.data()+ptr,Buf1D.data(),Len);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I try this :

```
Buf2D.resize(MaxCol);
Buf2d[index].resize(RowLength);
```

and then i use a loop for copy Buf1D to Column(index) of Buf2D .

```
for (i=0...) Buf2d[index][i] = Buf1D[i];
```

Thanks.